# cant restart closed JavaFX application thread and invoke start method on it.Reopening closed GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, system-tray

I made application that works in background even if GUI is not present.That means i use System tray to either close application or Start UI again.User at start have to open GUI and then if he decides to close it he still have option to open it thru sys tray.

Problem is-**After i close application window(GUI) JAVAFX application thread is closed, and even if i use references to invoke start() method from my system tray Object.It does nothing, not suprising.So how do i overcome this problem? Can i manually start FX application thread and *renew my ui*?**

My start method looks like this

```
  @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        fxc = new FXMLMainViewController();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource(
                        "....just fxml path"
                )
        );
        loader.setController(fxc);
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.getIcons().add(new javafx.scene.image.Image(Todo.class.getResourceAsStream(".....just image path")));

        stage.setTitle("TODO");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        if (isTray) {//protection from creating useless tray objects
            tray = new Tray(stage, this);
            isTray = false;
        }

        datMod.updateTable(fxc.tableView, fxc.getTcmns());

    }
```

My tray class:

```
public class Tray {

    private Stage stage;
    private Application application;

    public Tray(Stage stage, Application application) {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.application = application;
        hookTray();

    }

    private void hookTray() {
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        } else {
            try {
                Todo.icon = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(Todo.class.getResourceAsStream("....image path")), "TODO application",
                        createPopupMenu());
                Todo.icon.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        stage.setIconified(false);
                    });
                    //some popup test
                });
                SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(Todo.icon);

                //Thread.sleep(3000);
                Todo.icon.displayMessage("TODO", "Listener enabled",
                        TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

            } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private PopupMenu createPopupMenu() throws HeadlessException {
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu();

        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        MenuItem showWindow = new MenuItem("Show window");
        showWindow.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

            //restart ui thread /renew  gui

        });
        exit.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

            System.exit(0);
        });
        menu.add(showWindow);
        menu.add(exit);

        return menu;
    }

}
```

small note- i dont want to inconify my GUI, i want it to stop/remove it/no trace of it .Thats why i use system tray for it.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun bud there is no error to reproduce.This is almost MCVE  just ommmit update table.And put default FXML/icon paths.

Comment: @jewelsea Perfect exactly what i was looking for!